# Page Builder by SiteOrigin

Tags: wordpress

In mobile version content and images are overlaping using Page Builder by SiteOrigin worpress.

I have attached the screenshot also, Please give me the solution to display properly.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Questions seeking support for a plugin can either be answered by reading the documentation or should be directed to the plugin author. If you need help with a coding issue, you need to post the code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage with the help of layout section.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Koqi.jpg)